# Retaining properties in a way I never saw before?

Tags: objective-c, retain, getter-setter

I saw a sample code with this code:

in the .h file:

```
  CALayer *_animationLayer;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) CALayer *animationLayer;
```

And in the .m file:

```
  @synthesize animationLayer = _animationLayer;
```

I am guessing it is related to the retain count?

Can someone explain that?

Comment: I've tried my best to answer, but what specifically are you looking for?

Comment: trying to understand why use it, when and what is the benefit? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the .h file is declaring two things, a variable called `_animationLayer` which is of type `CALayer*`, and a property called `animationLayer` which is also of type `CALayer*`.  The code in the .m file is instructing the objective-c compiler to automatically generate getters and setters for the `animationLayer` property, using the `_animationLayer` variable to hold the actual value that is set.

So for instance:

```
_animationLayer = nil;  //initialize the variable to nil
self.animationLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];  //assign a value to the property
NSLog("_animationLayer is:  %@", _animationLayer);  //it's not set to nil anymore
_animationLayer = nil;  //set it to nil again
NSLog("self.animationLayer is:  %@", self.animationLayer);  //now the property is nil
```

And you're correct, this does have some relationship to the object's retainCount (so it's not quite correct to think of the variable as a direct alias for the property).  In essence, setting the value directly using the `_animationLayer` variable *does not* retain the new value or release the old value.  Setting the value using the property accessor does.  For example:

```
_animationLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];  //retain count is 1
self.animationLayer = nil;                 //retain count is 0

self.animationLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];  //oops, retain count is 2
self.animationLayer = nil;  //retain count is 1, the object leaked

_animationLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];  //retain count is 1
[_animationLayer release];               //retain count is 0
self.animationLayer = nil;               //oops, just released it again
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider it like an alias for the variable name.

From the [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW46):

> The syntax for `@synthesize` also
>   includes an extension that allows you
>   to use different names for the
>   property and its instance-variable
>   storage. Consider, for example, the
>   following statement:

```
@synthesize title, directReports, role = jobDescrip;
```

> This tells the computer to synthesize accessor methods for
>   properties `title`, `directReports`, and
>   `role`, **and to use the `jobDescrip`
>   instance variable to back the `role`
>   property.**